# How can I say "I am learning German in my spare time"

Tags: english-to-german, idiomaticity

The literal translation appears to be "Ich lerne Deutsch in meiner Freizeit".

Is this a natural sentence in German?

Comment: Your sentence is just fine. But maybe you could let us know where your doubts come from, to allow for better answers?

Answer (score 8):

The sentence you gave is perfectly fine. In most cases

> In meiner Freizeit lerne ich Deutsch.

would be more idiomatic. But I can imagine cases where the sentence you gave would be preferred over the latter sentence. Consider this:

> Ich lerne Deutsch in meiner Freizeit, Russisch aber im Dienst - und zwar im Rahmen meines Aufbaustudiums.

In the same context there are several options. The same person could say - and may prefer:

> Deutsch lerne ich in meiner Freizeit, Russisch aber im Dienst - und zwar im Rahmen meines Aufbaustudiums.

Answer (score 4):

Your translation is perfect. It is one of the possibilities German native speakers would use:

> Ich lerne Deutsch in meiner Freizeit.
>   Ich lerne in meiner Freizeit Deutsch.
>   In meiner Freizeit lerne ich Deutsch.

All three are good style and sound normal. None of the three is better or worse than the others.

The following sentence is also possible (since it is a correct German sentence):

> Deutsch lerne ich in meiner Freizeit.

But you better should use one of the former three sentences. German is very tolerant to word-order, so the last version is grammatically correct, but it is rarely used and sounds a little bit strange.

Comment: Agreed. But I would argue that the most neutral is “Ich lerne in meiner Freizeit Deutsch”.

Answer (score 3):

In German one would say:

> In meiner Freizeit lerne ich Deutsch.

Comment: This answer is misleading. It suggests that the sentence the OP was inquiring about was wrong, which it is not.

Comment: The OP asked if this is a natural sentence in German. In my opinion this is not a natural sentence in German.

Comment: Why not? It could not sound more natural to me. There may be differences in stress, with the OPs version stresses the spare time, and yours stresses the language learning, but since his exact intentions are currently unclear, i fail to see anything unnatural.

Comment: Welcome and thank you for joining. I think giving the OP a little more information about different stresses would have helped. At the same time I note that the OP gave no information, as to how his doubts arose. That leaves us to guess - or to prefer short answers, as you did.

Comment: @aGer: When asked: "Lernst du Deutsch in der Schule?", the answer "In meiner Freizeit lerne ich Deutsch." would be utterly **unnatural**, while what the OP wrote would sound absolutely fitting.